# How to convert this game code to Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, gamekit

I am an old programmer from way back but haven't done anything in a few (24) years. :). Things have changed a little.

I found some code that I'm trying to play around with but it seems the code was written in an earlier version of swift.  I have converted it to the best of my ability, and the programs compiles with no errors.  But the sprite node doesn't move at all.

Ultimately I'm trying to get a sprite node (player) to follow my touch as I drag it around the screen. and to stop when I stop touching.

If someone has a different way to accomplish the same goal that is fine also.

GameScene.swift

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

let trackingAgent = GKAgent2D()
var player = AgentNode()

var seekGoal : GKGoal = GKGoal()

let stopGoal = GKGoal(toReachTargetSpeed: 0)

var seeking : Bool = false {
    willSet {
        if newValue {
            self.player.agent.behavior?.setWeight(1, for: seekGoal)
            self.player.agent.behavior?.setWeight(0, for: stopGoal)
        }else{
            self.player.agent.behavior?.setWeight(0, for: seekGoal)
            self.player.agent.behavior?.setWeight(1, for: stopGoal)
        }
    }
}

var agentSystem = GKComponentSystem()

var lastUpdateTime : TimeInterval = 0

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    super.didMove(to: view)

    self.trackingAgent.position = vector_float2(Float(self.frame.midX), Float(self.frame.midY))

    self.agentSystem = GKComponentSystem(componentClass: GKAgent2D.self)

    self.player = AgentNode(scene: self, radius: Float(40.0), position: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY))

    self.player.agent.behavior = GKBehavior()
    self.agentSystem.addComponent(self.player.agent)

    self.seekGoal = GKGoal(toSeekAgent: self.trackingAgent)
}

override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if lastUpdateTime == 0 {
        lastUpdateTime = currentTime
    }

    let delta = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
    lastUpdateTime = currentTime
    self.agentSystem.update(deltaTime: delta)
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.seeking = true
    handleTouch(touches: touches)
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>?, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.seeking = false
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.seeking = false
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    handleTouch(touches: touches)
}

func handleTouch(touches:Set<UITouch>) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else {
        return
    }

    let location = touch.location(in: self)

    self.trackingAgent.position = vector_float2(Float(location.x), Float(location.y))
}
}
```

AgentNode.swift

```
import GameplayKit
import SpriteKit

class AgentNode : SKNode, GKAgentDelegate {
var agent = GKAgent2D()

var triangleShape = SKShapeNode()

override init(){
    super.init()
}

init(scene:SKScene, radius:Float, position:CGPoint) {
    super.init()

    self.position = position
    self.zPosition = 10;
    scene.addChild(self)

    agent.radius = radius
    agent.position = vector_float2(Float(position.x), Float(position.y))
    agent.delegate = self
    agent.maxSpeed = 100 * 4
    agent.maxAcceleration = 50 * 4

    let ship = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")
    ship.setScale(1.0 / 8.0)
    ship.zRotation = CGFloat(-Double.pi / 2.0)
    self.addChild(ship)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func agentWillUpdate(agent: GKAgent) {

}

private func agentDidUpdate(agent: GKAgent) {
    guard let agent2D = agent as? GKAgent2D else {
        return
    }

    self.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(agent2D.position.x), y: CGFloat(agent2D.position.y))
    self.zRotation = CGFloat(agent2D.rotation)
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Zbud68 welcome to SO!  I really want you to get the help you need so here's a quick tip: If you tag your question with the technologies you're using, it'll be easier for people to find and respond to your question :).

Comment: thanks for the tip.  First time i've posted

Comment: I only made a quick glance over your code, but you are missing super calls on your touches functions. Just start typing under one of the function definitions "super.touches..." and autofill should take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two functions should not be private. And change to delegate's signature. It's working now. Have fun.

```
   func agentWillUpdate(_ agent: GKAgent) {

}



func agentDidUpdate(_ agent: GKAgent) {
    guard let agent2D = agent as? GKAgent2D else {
        return
    }

    self.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(agent2D.position.x), y: CGFloat(agent2D.position.y))
    self.zRotation = CGFloat(agent2D.rotation)
}
```

Comment: Working great now, appreciate the help